# What does the dissociative mechanism for cis/trans interconversion of [Mo(CO)4(PPh3)2] look like?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stereochemistry, molecular-structure, isomers, cis-trans-isomerism

All I can find in the literature is that the *cis*→*trans* interconversion proceeds via dissociation of one of the PPh<sub>3</sub> ligands resulting in a square-pyramidal C<sub>s</sub> intermediate, with the remaining PPh<sub>3</sub> in an axial position.

I assume it proceeds via either dissociation of the CO *trans* to the PPh<sub>3</sub>, followed by PPh<sub>3</sub> and CO binding again to form the *trans* isomer; or via a Berry pseudorotation-like conversion of the square pyramidal intermediate, however considering that the former seems unlikely due to the CO being a more strongly binding ligand than PPh<sub>3</sub> and the latter would require quite a bit of energy, neither of these make sense to me.

[image]

Comment: More specifics are needed in the question, but it's possible that the square pyramid is in equilibrium with a trigonal pyramid (simple isomerization). That allows blurring of what it means to be cis and trans.

Comment: I'm not sure what how to be more specific, any suggestions welcomed. Also I assume you meant trigonal bipyramid?

Comment: Oh, the complex is given in the title... Yes, I meant bipyramid. There aren't too many viable options here. I don't have a reference right now, but I remember seeing something similar before.